# Chrome Browser HAR File incomplete

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

I downloaded a HAR but it does not contain data from third party trackers such as LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter.  I can see the files load on the network tab buy they are not included in the HAR file when I dowload it.   Does anyone know why this might be the case and how I can work around it?

Comment: Same issue here, Chrome 83-86 on Linux. When I try to view the response data in the network console it just says `Failed to load response data`. The response headers show a content-length and if I request the resources directly they show content. Solution is that Firefox works flawlessly and produces a better & more reliable HAR file than Chrome.